# Drupal 7 links generated by views do not appear on the home page for anonymous users

Tags: drupal, view, hyperlink

Is there a way to set up a home page of views (with links) visible for all (anonymous) users, but authentication is required to view each link's contents ? We prefer not to require a login before getting to the home page, so as to encourage users to see what's on the site. (Similar to news sites like the New York Times which allow free access to home and section pages but require subscription to see the content)

I am able to create the views, and give access to the home page only for
anonymous users (using the Front Page module).  Drupal will automatically present the login form.

The problem is that the links generated by the views do not appear on the home page for anonymous users because the linked content itself requires authentication.

Is there is no built-in feature in Drupal or external module to display the link (regardless of permission) ?  If not, the only thing I can think of is to set up our own home page module, and generate the links so they can be visible.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a view that listed some content links that showed to users not authorized to see the contents of such links:

- Be sure to use the option "Bypass content access control" checkbox when creating such a view or check "Specify validation criteria" and "Validate user has access to the content" appropiately.
- Disable unnecesary relationships on the query, as they are a known source of restricting access to content by checking content access controls

Please post this question on [drupal.stackexchange.com](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) to get more answers.

Comment: thanks Carlos for the tips, I will try them out as soon as I return to the office!